# Laravel Pivot - Getting same model through related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot, relationship

I have a table setup like this with pivot relationship already set.

```
users           colonies       colony_user
.----.-------.  .----.------. .-----------.---------.
| id | name  |  | id | name | | colony_id | user_id |
'----+-------'  '----+------' '-----------+---------+
| 1  | steve |  | 1  | col1 | | 1         | 1       |
| 2  | kate  |  | 2  | col2 | | 1         | 2       |
| 3  | sven  |  '----'------' | 2         | 1       |
'----'-------'                | 2         | 3       |
                              '-----------'---------'
```

```
    // User Model
    public function colonies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Colony::class);
    }

    // Colony Model
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

I can get all colonies from a user and vice versa through eloquent relationship.
Example: `$user->colonies()->get()` or `$colony->users()->get()`.
What I want to get though are other users from the same colonies I am part with.

With that table provided, if I am `user_id=1`,  I want to get both user `2` and `3` because user `2` is my colleague from colony `1` and user `3` from colony `2`.

I was thinking something like this `$user->colonies()->users()->where('id', '<>', $user->id)->get()` but to no avail.

Hope anyone can help, this is really giving me a headache :(

Sorry about the confusing title, not a native english speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to eager load the users for each colony you're a part of:

```
$user->colonies()->with(['users' => function ($q) use ($user) {
    $q->whereKeyNot($user->id);
}])->get();
```

Then you'd loop over the colonies and can access all the users.

Comment: thanks for the answer. How would it work though if I want to paginate the users that I'm getting?

Comment: You're throwing a curveball at me there, you didn't mention pagination in the question, haha. Do you just want a unique list of users or do you need them grouped by their colony(ies)?

Comment: @scpn since the result is a collection, you could paginate the collection using [forPage](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-forpage)

Comment: @DigitalDrifter sorry about that. I don't actually need them grouped. Just wanted them paginated. Although that should work for me, I'll just do the pagination manually like Arun suggested. Thanks a lot!